# I've created a simple .onion site, but instead of the Tor browser displaying my index.html file, it displays my folders

Tags: python, linux, web-hosting, tor

This is my first question so please bear with me. I looked for answers to my question, but found none unique to my issue.

I recently tried my hand at hosting an onion site with Python3 and the Tor browser. I created a directory called "tor_service" and placed a simple index.html file inside.

I then ran `python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 8080` in the same folder. Next, I opened another terminal session and started the Tor client. I navigated to, and appropriately modified the torrc file under the "hidden services" section, using port 8080. I opened my browser and went to localhost:8080 to verify everything was working. To my surprise, I saw the simple web page I wrote. So far, so good.

I then navigated to the Tor folder that contained the hostname to get the unique oinion address, and using `cat hostname`, obtained the string of characters followed by .onion.

I pasted the onion address in the Tor browser and again, I saw the simple html page I wrote.

Here's the problem: when I shut down my computer for the night, resumed the next day, and started the Python server and Tor client, instead of displaying my web page, I got a page that read "Directory of /" that displayed all of the folders on my hard drive. This is obviously a serious security issue. Not only were the folders on my hard drive on display for the web to see, they were all hyperlinks.

I don't understand what I did wrong. I didn't modify or move any files or change any settings, and I started the Python http.server and Tor client as usual.

I closed the terminal windows opened new ones, but got the same results. A third time resulted in the same outcome. I understand that using the Python "server" isn't the optimal method to host a site, but if I can't get something so simple to work, I fear I won't be able to actually write (much less diagnose problems on) a more robust server that operates using more than a single line of code.

I'm using the Linux subsystem on Windows 10 and the latest iteration of Ubuntu (20.4, I think).

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. I can craft and style a nice looking webpage, but I'd like to get proficient at the back-end side of things.

Comment: Are you looking for this site to be used by other consumers ? If your answer is yes, then I would suggest you to please rethink for making use of the Simple HTTP server provided by Python, as the owners themselves claim it's not fit for production: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have navigated back to the project folder in your terminal?

If you're running the

`python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 8080`

command immediately after opening the terminal, it will run in the 'default' folder rather than your project folder (you'll need to 'move' back into the project folder using [`cd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cd.1p.html)).

Comment: Yes, I'm running the server from my project folder. It seems python isn't recognizing my index.html page but, rather simply displaying the contents of the project folder. I tried the same process with a non-hidden service html project, and the index page seems to display, (minus the images for some reason). I've double- and triple-checked all of my file paths, and there are no errors.